# ABAP free internal table

Tags: refresh, abap, internals

The answer to the question below is given as 2. Why does refresh delete only the first row? Is it not expected that it deletes all rows of an internal table?

What will be output by the following code?

```
DATA: BEGIN OF itab OCCURS 0, fval type i, END OF itab. 

itab­-fval = 1. APPEND itab.

itab­-fval = 2. APPEND itab.

REFRESH itab.

WRITE: /1 itab­-fval.
```

A: 1

B: 2

C: blank

D: 0

Answer: B

Comment: E: Syntax error

Comment: What is `A:1`? Do you expect it should be an ABAP-command?

Comment: Why don't you run the code by yourself and see?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a quiz question or homework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the code did not contain any syntax errors, e.g. the missing '-' when assigning the value 2 and when writing the value, then B is the correct answer but not for the reason you state. It is not that the `REFRESH` only removes the first line from the table, it is because `REFRESH` does not clear the header line of the table. So after the `REFRESH` the header line still has the latest assigned value which is 2. This can be easily ascertained when running the program in the debugger.

Note that the use of internal table with header lines is obsolete, as mentioned in [SAP help](https://help.sap.com/viewer/10a002cd6c531014b5e1cb16d2455072/7.0.36/en-US/fceb384e358411d1829f0000e829fbfe.html).

Comment: This is what i am missing. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a clear command to clear the header line.

```
REFRESH itab.
CLEAR itab.
```